# Exchange shared mailbox login

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I have a client account that wishes to share his Office 365 inbox with a personal assistant, but obviously still wants to use the account himself, and the assistant has their own account.

Sharing login credentials is obviously one way, but not ideal. I was thinking of switching it to a shared mailbox, but there are [some comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/about-shared-mailboxes?view=o365-worldwide) suggesting this use isn't "intended". That's obviously not a comment on whether this will work or cause any issues.

Does anyone have any experience of knowledge of whether this configuration will work? I would normally just try it but this account is important and the client is not tech savvy so if the account becomes disabled or the password is reset in this conversion process, that would be extremely inconvenient to get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, converting it to a Shared mailbox is not the correct thing to do.

What you need to do is to grant the assistant one or more of the delegated permissions listed below to the mailbox in question:

Full Access

Send As

Send on Behalf